# By using Power Automate, unzip the file content in SharePoint Library . But if upload large file power automate is failed to unzip the file content

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

Uploaded the zip file in to the sharepoint library . By using power automate flow , unzip (Extracting the zip file ) in the same library . If File size is more than GB , it is failed to extract.

it shows the below error.

> Archive content is too large. It contains more than '100' files or more than '314572800' bytes in total.

Comment: Your question is too hard to understand; please edit it to clarify what you are trying to do and what the error is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.